# HLS Playback functionality for WPF/WinForms

Tags: windows, .net, media-player

I'm looking for a library/plugin that provides HLS (Http Live Streaming) playback for Windows Presentation Framework or Windows Forms (That I'll them embed in WPF).
The existing MediaElement class doesn't provide any streaming functionality within WPF. I'm aware of a number of solutions that wrap VLC Player to provide additional media functionality within WPF/WinForms. Unfortunately the HLS playback within VLC is quite poor and doesn't provide correct timecode information.

What options are there available that provide:

- HLS Playback embedded within an existing application
- Playback of both Live and VOD content.
- Playback of Live content with a rewind buffer.
- Access to both relative and absolute timecodes (if available)

Comment: Do you have any news regarding your question? I have a very simmilar problem and all i found besides VLC, which isnt an option for me, is: [HTTP Live Streaming Adapter](http://www.3ivx.com/technology/windows/metro/http_live_streaming.html) Probably would do the trick, but seems to be only for win8 and non-free

Comment: I wound up using an MPlayer wrapper as the VLC support for HLS is sub-optimal. I did look at that HLS Adapter for Win 8. I sent them a contact request but received no response.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Elecard hls source filter.
you can use it in conjuction to thier hls sink.
along with nginx as server.
it all directshow.